# Browser asks Windows login

Tags: javascript

I 've seen it in some sites, now I saw it in ebay. It asks for sign-in using Windows mechanisms (face/pin/fingerprint) etc.

Is there a defined javascript API to do that in my own site? Is this one the one I need ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Authentication_API

Comment: Yes, Webauthn is what you're looking for. See https://webauthn.guide/ for more details.